# Keeping save files of steam games so i can do a fresh windows install

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

I want to perform a clean install of windows. Some of the steam games I own have save files that aren't stored to the Steam Cloud. How can I save these save files so I can continue my progress on them?

I am aware that some games use steam cloud to sync save files and other stuff. But what about the rest?

Comment: What do you mean by "Offline Steam games"? Like Single player-only games?

Comment: Ah yes. Basically any game that is not online only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the game. Most games will store files that need to be arbitrarily saved in `%localappdata%` or `%appdata%`. This usually includes save files and mods if applicable. Some games will store save files in the user's user folder (e.g. `C:\Users\[YourUserName]\`), or a subfolder of that (e.g. "My Saves", or "Documents").

I recommend searching for each of the games you want to keep your save files of to search online where the save files are kept. Afterwards you will need to put the save files back in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Check Computer > Local Disk(C:) > Program Files/(x86) > Steam > steamapps > common. That is where all steam game files are stored.

Comment: I know where my steamapps folder is, it's not on C :) but are you sure? I checked a few and it's not there

Comment: A process (and thus the game) needs administrator privileges to save in `C:\Program Files/`, which is why the only time when someone would write to that place is to install something.